# GWT: Make PopupPanel disappear when the mouse goes out

Tags: gwt, popup, panel

Here is GWT `PopupPanel` ShowCase:
http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwBasicPopup

The Panel got hide when the user click out the panel..

What I need is to make it hide when the use move the mouse out the area of the Panel...

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
yourPopupPanel.addDomHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
    public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
        yourPopupPanel.hide();
    }
}, MouseOutEvent.getType());
```

Comment: `addDomHandler` NOT FOUND UNDER PopupPanel!

Comment: Are you sure you have imported the right PopupPanel(`com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel`)? When you look at the doc for PopupPanel http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html you can see that it inherits `addDomHandler` from `Widget`.

Comment: In GWT2.0>>>> `The method addDomHandler(H, DomEvent.Type<H>) from the type Widget is not visible`

Answer (score 0):

```
    popuppanel.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler()

{
  public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event)
   {
      popuppanel.hide();
    }
    });
```